# Livewire V3 form element not keeping in sync with the component value

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have the following live wire component

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class HelloWorld extends Component
{
    public $message;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->message = 'Hello World!';
    }

    public function clearMessage(): void
    {
        $this->reset();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.hello-world');
    }

}
```

and the following blade :

```
<div>
    <input wire:model.live="message" type="text" name="message" id="message">

    <button wire:click.prevent="clearMessage" type="button">Clear</button>

    <h1>{{ $message }}</h1>
</div>
```

When I click the clear button the `{{ $message }}` element gets cleared but the value of the `<input>` element does not get cleared.

I would expect all elements referencing the livewire component variables to be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Breeze has Alpine.js enabled by default in the resources/js/app.js file

Livewire v3 also comes with Alpine built-in and pre-configured already.

Solution remove alpine from resourse/js/app/js

```
import './bootstrap';

// import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
// import focus from '@alpinejs/focus';
// Alpine.plugin(focus);
// Alpine.start();
```